# F# Threading Changing State Through Unfold

Tags: f#, seq

I'm trying to process a sequence of items whereby the process step relies on some additional cumulative state from the prior items (ordering isn't important).

Essentially:

1. I have a `Seq<'A>`
2. I have a `(Type * int) list` referred to as the `skip list`
3. I have a process step `'A -> (Type * int) list -> 'B option`

   - This takes the current skip list

The method in question essentially:

`Seq<'A'> -> (Type * int) list -> (Type * int) list`

So we take a bunch of input items and an initial skip list and produce a final skip list.

I've basically got the following so far:

```
sourceItems
|> Seq.map (fun srcItem -> (srcItem, outerSkip))
|> Seq.unfold (fun elem ->
    match elem with
    | SeqEmpty -> None
    | SeqCons((srcItem, skip), tail) -> 
        match process(srcItem, skip) with
        | Some targetItem -> Some((Some targetItem, skip), tail)
        | None -> Some((None, skip), tail |> Seq.map (fun (i, skp) -> (i, (srcItem.GetType(), liD srcItem) :: skp))))
```

With `SeqEmpty` and `SeqCons` being active patterns:

```
let (|SeqEmpty|SeqCons|) (xs: 'a seq) =
    if Seq.isEmpty xs then SeqEmpty
    else SeqCons(Seq.head xs, Seq.skip 1 xs)
```

My process so far basically just starts off with the items and adds the initial skip to each, unfolds and maps the remaining seq to have the same item but with the new skip list.

I have a number of problems with this:

1. It's ugly and confusing as all hell
2. I'm sure it's less than performant

Ideally I'd like to avoid the need to map the items to include the initial skip list in the first place, but then I'm not sure how I'd get that into the unfold aside from mapping it into just the first element in the sequence.

---

### Possible Alternative Solution

Based on a different approach taken in [List processing with intermediate state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517639/list-processing-with-intermediate-state?rq=1) (Mark's answer)

I've been able to use:

```
items
|> Seq.fold (fun (skip) srcItem ->
    match process(srcItem, skip) with
    | None -> (srcItem.GetType(), liD srcItem) :: skip
    | Some tgtItem ->
        skip
    ) outerSkip
```

Which aside from all the stuff needed when there is an item, appears to actually do the trick!

This is **significantly** simpler than the unfold approach, but I'm a little unclear on exactly how it's working.

I'm assuming that `fun (skip) srcItem -> ...` is essentially creating a function expecting an additional parameter that through the magic of something (partial application?) I'm able to provide to `fold` using `outerSkip` - is this right?

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer as part of your question.  If you have a new question, make a new post for it.  (You are allowed to answer your own question).

Comment: @mydogisbox the "solution" still forms part of the question - it's intended to guide the answer.

Comment: 'Why' is very different from 'how'. "appears to actually do the trick!"  You have an answer you just don't understand it.  That's a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adopting the fold strategy as mentioned in the question.

The final code is:

```
let result =
    items
    |> Seq.fold (fun (skip, targetItems), srcItem ->
        match process(srcItem, skip) with
        | None -> ((srcItem.GetType(), getId srcItem) :: skip, targetItems)
        | Some tgtItem -> (skip, tgtItem :: targetItems)) (outerSkip, [])
```

With `result` being a tuple `((Type * int) list, obj list)` which is exactly what I wanted.

I'm then able to take action on the target items, and to just return the final skip list.

This is a **huge** improvement over the unfold method I was using previously.