# What is this fold actually doing?

Tags: syntax, f#, fold

As part of my question ([F# Threading Changing State Through Unfold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431817/f-threading-changing-state-through-unfold)) I stumbled upon a solution using the `Seq.fold` function, but the syntax looked strange to me.

Essentially:

```
items
|> Seq.fold (fun (someState) theItem -> ....) someInitialState
```

I get what it's doing functionally, but I'm not entirely sure **how** it's doing it...

Is specifying `SomeState` separately in parentheses creating a curried function that `someInitialState` is then being partially applied to?

I don't think this is something specific to the fold function, and is likely just utilising a functional principle that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses do nothing. This is just how the folder looks like.

If you look at the type of fold:

```
Seq.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> seq<'T> -> 'State
```

The folder function is of type `'State -> 'T -> 'State`. This means it takes a state and an element, and returns a new state. And indeed it's curried, but that's not really important here.

The way `fold` uses that function is by taking the initial state, applying the folder to that initial state and the first element, then applying the folder to the resulting state and the second element, and so on...

Comment: So presumably a fold of `fun item -> ...` with no additional state is an overload? OR is it just implicitly accepting unit?

Comment: I would say it's a fold used in a wrong way ;) There's no such overload in standard, perhaps it's something you have wrote in-house (in which case I suggest taking a good look at it).

Comment: It could be a partially applied folder, but to match the signature the first argument would be the accumulator rather than item.

Comment: I think I've actually had a brainfart and forgotten what fold **actually** is and as a result confused it with something else, forgetting that fold is taking state and reducing.

Comment: The basic answer to my question here is "the fold is doing a fold and you've been silly" haha.

Comment: @Clint - you might be thinking of [`Seq.reduce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353740.aspx) which is similar to `fold` except that it doesn't have a separate State parameter.

Comment: @Clint - Don't worry, it happens to us all! But if you don't think this question will be useful to anyone in future, you might as well delete it.